# how to improve performance of web applications?

Tags: javascript

We have created web app using vanilla JavaScript. Please suggest some ways by which I can improve performance of web app.How can I improve performance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of ways you can improve web performance. Some common things are listed in below link :-

https://www.keycdn.com/blog/front-end-optimization/

If you are using vanilla javascript then along with above tips in link I would suggest read below links (I found them handy when I worked with vanilla javascript) :-

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_best_practices.asp
https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml

And for javascript you should atleast practise below concepts very thoroughly (This will improve code quality and your knowledge):-

http://javascriptissexy.com/16-javascript-concepts-you-must-know-well/

Comment: Thanks for sharing this